Writing custom behavex json parser to allure2 format
I'm using behaveX plugin on top of behave framework in order to speed up my tests.
However I would like to parse the results into allure format which is more convinient.
I wrote my own custom json report parser basing on allure-commons package, which should convert behaveX report into allure friendly json format.
The problem is that after parsing, both files seem almost identicall and contain the same keys, but allure displayes empty report when running command "allure serve" .
What am I doing wrong ?
Code here:
https://github.com/BackstageBones/Selenium-Behave/blob/main/conversion_tool.py
Documentation I followed:
https://allurereport.org/docs/how-it-works-test-result-file/
side by side comparison - on the left my parsed behavex json
on the right - allure-behave json
side by side json comparison

This question is similar to: Allure not displaying results. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
